# Using GroupBy and show different Sums based on conditions - LINQ Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, lambda, group-by, sum

I have a table with 3 columns.

[image]

And I would like to present a table with this structure:

[image]

Can someone show me how to do this with Lambda expressions?

So far I've only gotten the result if I only wanted to show one column:

```
var sum_data = _context.HechosFinanza
                .Where(x => x.Product.Sale_Type == "Cash Sale")
                .GroupBy(x => x.Product.Product_Name)
                .Select(x => Product { Tienda = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(s => 
s.sales_amount) });
```

I don't know if something like this may be possible (no idea really, just trying to figure it out):

```
var sum_data = _context.HechosFinanza
                // I remove there where condition from here
                .GroupBy(x => x.Product.Product_Name)
                // And I add the where condition in each sum
                .Select(x => Product { Tienda = x.Key, 
                         TotalCash = x.Sum(s => s.sales_amount).Where(s => s.Product.Sale_Type == "Cash Sale"),
                         TotalCredit = x.Sum(s => s.sales_amount).Where(s.Product.Sale_Type == "Credit Sale") 
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, well. It turns out I was really close.

Just had to put the 'Where' statement before.

Answer:

```
var sum_data = _context.HechosFinanza
                // I remove there where condition from here
                .GroupBy(x => x.Product.Product_Name)
                // And I add the where condition in each sum
                .Select(x => Product { Tienda = x.Key, 
                         TotalCash = x.Where(s => s.Product.Sale_Type == "Cash Sale").Sum(s => s.sales_amount),
                         TotalCredit = x.Where(s.Product.Sale_Type == "Credit Sale") .Sum(s => s.sales_amount)
            });
```

And done.